# loading (deserializing) _quickly_ 2MB of Data in Android on Application Startup

Tags: java, android, performance, deserialization, protocol-buffers

I need to load around 2MB of data quickly on startup of my Android application.
I really need *all* this data in memory, so something like SQLite etc. is not an alternative.

The data consists of about 3000 `int[][]` arrays. The array dimension is around [7][7] on average.

I first implemented some prototype on my desktop, and ported it to android. On the desktop, I simply used Java's (de)serialization. Deserialization of that data takes about 90ms on my desktop computer.

However on Android 2.2.1 the same process takes about 15seconds(!) on my HTC Magic. It's so slow that if I don't to the deserialization in a seperate thred, my app will be killed. All in all, this is unacceptably slow.

What am I doing wrong? Should I

- switch to something like *protocol buffers*? Would that really speed up the process of deserialization of several magnitudes - after all, it's not complex objects that I am deserializing, just `int[][]` arrays?!
- design my own custom binary file format? I've never done that before, and no clue where to start
- do something else?

Comment: What is the data? What does "need .. in memory" *really* mean?

Comment: When you took the time to run Traceview and determine precisely where and why it took "15seconds(!)", what did you find?

Comment: Minor note: protocol buffers does not directly support jagged arrays. It does support vectors though, and there is a "packed" option to make it efficient, but you'd need to store a `repeated Something` where `Something` *has* a `repeated int data = 1 [packed=true];`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not bypass the built-in deserialization, and use direct binary I/O?
When speed is your primary concern, not necessarily ease of programming, you can't beat it.

For output the pseudo-code would look like this:

```
write number of arrays
for each array
  write n,m array sizes
  for each element of array
    write array element
```

For input, the pseudo-code would be:

```
read number of arrays
for each array
  read n,m array sizes
  allocate the array
  for each element of array
    read array element
```

When you read/write numbers in binary, you bypass all the conversion between binary and characters.
The speed should be limited only by the data transfer rate of the file storage media.

Comment: Nit: serialization/deserialization does *not* imply "conversion between binary and characters"; and even a solution such as this must somehow move the binary stream data into `int[][]` (or provide a wrapper like IntBuffer) as, unlike C, there is no way to just "cast that pointer value".

Comment: @pst: Thx. In my experience, since this is basically an I/O task, it should be I/O bound. If I pause it, it should almost always be in the process of emptying or filling a buffer from the device. When this kind of operation takes much too long, it is doing a whole lot of stuff other than actual I/O. In C or C++ or C# there's no casting, you just read/write the raw bytes of the data in/out of the storage you've allocated for it.

Comment: This looks the right way, however I would add one more level. I've some experience with Android systems. IO is really an issue, so instead of reading each array element in a loop, first read all 2MB data into an in memory buffer (system level buffers will be extremely suitable for this size, reading will be fast as reading a single record), then parse it. This may create another 2MB heap allocation on the heap for a while but it worths it.

Comment: @auselen: I guess you're saying you can't count on adequate buffering by the built-in I/O support. Maybe so.

Answer (score 1):

after trying out several things, as Mike Dunlavey suggested, direct binary I/O seemed fastest. I almost verbatim used his sketched out version. For completeness however, and if someone else wants to try, I'll post my full code here; even though it's very basic and without any kind of sanity check. This is for reading such a binary stream; writing is absolutely analogous.

```
import java.io.*;

public static int[][][] readBinaryInt(String filename) throws IOException {
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(
            new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename)));
int dimOfData = in.readInt();
int[][][] patternijk = new int[dimofData][][];
for(int i=0;i<dimofData;i++) {
    int dimStrokes = in.readInt(); 
    int[][] patternjk = new int[dimStrokes][];      
    for(int j=0;j<dimStrokes;j++) {
        int dimPoints = in.readInt();
        int[] patternk = new int[dimPoints];
        for(int k=0;k<dimPoints;k++) {
                patternk[k] = in.readInt();
            }
            patternjk[j] = patternk;
    }
    patternijk[i] = patternjk;
    }
    in.close();
return patternijk;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of issues on a project some months ago. I think you should split your file in various parts, and only load relevant parts following a choice from the user for example.
Hope it will be helpful!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But as stated above, I really need to operate on _all_ data, and thus have all of the data in memory. Loading only some part is not an option.

Comment: And you do need to operate on *all* data simultaneously?

Answer (score -1):

I dont know your data but if you optimize your loop, it will effect the deserialize time  unbelievably.

if you look at example below

> ```
> computeRecursively(30);
>
> computeRecursivelyWithLoop(30); // 270 milisecond    
>
> computeIteratively(30);        // 1 milisecond            
>
> computeRecursivelyFasterUsingBigInteger(30); // about twice s fast as before version          
>
> computeRecursivelyFasterUsingBigIntegerAllocations(50000);   // only 1.3 Second !!!
> ```

```
public class Fibo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // try the methods
    }

    public static long computeRecursively(int n) {

        if (n > 1) {
            System.out.println(computeRecursively(n - 2)
                    + computeRecursively(n - 1));
            return computeRecursively(n - 2) + computeRecursively(n - 1);
        }
        return n;
    }

    public static long computeRecursivelyWithLoop(int n) {
        if (n > 1) {
            long result = 1;
            do {
                result += computeRecursivelyWithLoop(n - 2);
                n--;
            } while (n > 1);
            System.out.println(result);
            return result;
        }
        return n;
    }

    public static long computeIteratively(int n) {
        if (n > 1) {
            long a = 0, b = 1;
            do {
                long tmp = b;
                b += a;
                a = tmp;
                System.out.println(a);
            } while (--n > 1);
            System.out.println(b);
            return b;
        }
        return n;
    }

    public static BigInteger computeRecursivelyFasterUsingBigInteger(int n) {
        if (n > 1) {
            int m = (n / 2) + (n & 1); // not obvious at first – wouldn’t it be
                                        // great to have a better comment here?
            BigInteger fM = computeRecursivelyFasterUsingBigInteger(m);
            BigInteger fM_1 = computeRecursivelyFasterUsingBigInteger(m - 1);
            if ((n & 1) == 1) {
                // F(m)^2 + F(m-1)^2
                System.out.println(fM.pow(2).add(fM_1.pow(2)));
                return fM.pow(2).add(fM_1.pow(2)); // three BigInteger objects
                                                    // created
            } else {
                // (2*F(m-1) + F(m)) * F(m)
                System.out.println( fM_1.shiftLeft(1).add(fM).multiply(fM));
                return fM_1.shiftLeft(1).add(fM).multiply(fM); // three
                                                                // BigInteger
                                                                // objects
                                                                // created
            }
        }
        return (n == 0) ? BigInteger.ZERO : BigInteger.ONE; // no BigInteger
                                                            // object created
    }

    public static long computeRecursivelyFasterUsingBigIntegerAllocations(int n) {
        long allocations = 0;
        if (n > 1) {
            int m = (n / 2) + (n & 1);
            allocations += computeRecursivelyFasterUsingBigIntegerAllocations(m);
            allocations += computeRecursivelyFasterUsingBigIntegerAllocations(m - 1);
            // 3 more BigInteger objects allocated
            allocations += 3;
            System.out.println(allocations);
        }
        return allocations; // approximate number of BigInteger objects
                            // allocated when
                            // computeRecursivelyFasterUsingBigInteger(n) is
                            // called
    }
}
```